# How to write files on a server with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Environment: network, where each client is connected to a server. Internet access is disabled. The server cannot run server-side scripting languages or similar things, it can only be used to host files. [You know, the school server.]
Context: a chat which just shows a page (`chat.html`) which people edit in order to write a message. Simplified code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
<iframe src="chat.html">
```

Problem: editing may overwrite precedent edits.
Additional notices: The clients are (theorically) not allowed to run external programs.

The solution I thought about is the following: making a `<form>` which, once you send the message, edits `chat.html`, appends the message and closes the file. The problem is that I don't know how to open files. Also, I cannot use libraries like jQuery and so on, because the computer is "closed" (cannot access the Internet, nor download files from an USB drive).
What have I tried so far: Googled a while, but no solutions for opening files. *Quite* the same for SO: JS cannot access *local* files due to safety issues, but nothing about accessing files on servers.

Comment: Using JavaScript call server side action. Like you can use servlet to post your file to server.

Comment: Javascript runs on client side. The server is a different computer that the client does not know anything about. So it obviously has no access to the server side filesystem.

Comment: @Esailija Not just server files. Browser scripts don't have file access at all.

Comment: @Esailija The client has read and write permissions on the server, anyway ("a page (...) which people edit in order to write a message").

Comment: @GolezTrol yes [they do with "html5"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) or flash

Comment: @Esailija That works only with a file that was preselected by the user. Flash (and Java, for that matter) are a different story. They are separate applications running in a browsers and can hardly be seen as browser scripts.

Comment: @GolezTrol Flash isn't a different story, I just mentioned it because it can be used as a fallback for "html5". Flash is also extremely restricted in browsers and can't read files any easier than "html5". But reading files from local filesystem, modifying them and then prompting download and saving them is possible with just local client side javascript given a modern browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Client side Javascript cannot edit server files. Or any files for that matter. You will need service side scripting of any kind if you want to store files on the server.

The addition of libraries like JQuery wouldn't help either. They are just Javascript 'helpers' but cannot do anything that you cannot do using Javascript alone.